# Ruby each_with_index offset

Tags: ruby, iteration

Can I define the offset of the index in the each_with_index loop iterator?
My straight forward attempt failed:

```
some_array.each_with_index{|item, index = 1| some_func(item, index) }
```

Edit:

Clarification: I don't want an array offset I want that the index within the each_with_index doesn't start from 0 but e.g. 1.

Comment: what Ruby version do you use?

Comment: Sorry for not writing, but I use Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Actually, [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerator.html#M000303) receives offset as an optional parameter:

```
[:foo, :bar, :baz].to_enum.with_index(1).each do |elem, i|
  puts "#{i}: #{elem}"
end
```

outputs:

```
1: foo
2: bar
3: baz
```

BTW, I think it is there only in 1.9.2.

Comment: in 1.8.7 it's only `with_index` no params, indexes from `0`

Comment: actually, an even shorter answer is possible, please see mine below.

Answer (score 54):

The following is succinct, using Ruby's Enumerator class.

```
[:foo, :bar, :baz].each.with_index(1) do |elem, i|
    puts "#{i}: #{elem}"
end
```

output

```
1: foo
2: bar
3: baz
```

Array#each returns an enumerator, and calling Enumerator#with_index returns another enumerator, to which a block is passed.

Answer (score 5):

1) The simplest is to substitute `index+1` instead of `index` to the function:

```
some_array.each_with_index{|item, index| some_func(item, index+1)}
```

but probably that is not what you want.

2) The next thing you can do is to define a different index `j` within the block and use it instead of the original index:

```
some_array.each_with_index{|item, i| j = i + 1; some_func(item, j)}
```

3) If you want to use index in this way often, then define another method:

```
module Enumerable
  def each_with_index_from_one *args, &pr
    each_with_index(*args){|obj, i| pr.call(obj, i+1)}
  end
end

%w(one two three).each_with_index_from_one{|w, i| puts "#{i}. #{w}"}
# =>
1. one
2. two
3. three
```

---

**Update**

This answer, which was answered a few years ago, is now obsolete. For modern Rubies, Zack Xu's answer will work better.

Comment: the bad thing that it will itarate even after there is no more elements in array

Comment: @fl00r Really? In my example, it stops after three.

Comment: But if offset is 2 or 10? In your case offset is zero. I mean here is no any offset in your (3)

Comment: @fl00r You just change the `+1` in my code to `+2` or `+10`. Its works as well.

Comment: OMG, author edited his post, so he need index offset not the array.

Comment: so +1, because I was doing another job :) waste job

Comment: @sawa: Thanks for the answer and the aditional option. 
@fl00r: Sorry for not being clear at my first approach of formulating the question and therefore wasting your time.

Answer (score 4):

If `some_index` is somehow meaningful, then consider using a hash, rather than an array.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into it.

My solution not necessary is the best, but it just worked for me.

In the view iteration:

just add: index + 1

That's all for me, as I don't use any reference to those index numbers but just for show in a list.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can

```
some_array[offset..-1].each_with_index{|item, index| some_func(item, index) }
some_array[offset..-1].each_with_index{|item, index| some_func(item, index+offset) }
some_array[offset..-1].each_with_index{|item, index| index+=offset; some_func(item, index) }
```

**UPD**

Also I should notice that if offset is more than your Array size it will though an error. Because:

```
some_array[1000,-1] => nil
nil.each_with_index => Error 'undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass'
```

What can we do here:

```
 (some_array[offset..-1]||[]).each_with_index{|item, index| some_func(item, index) }
```

Or to prevalidate offset:

```
 offset = 1000
 some_array[offset..-1].each_with_index{|item, index| some_func(item, index) } if offset <= some_array.size
```

This is little hacky

**UPD 2**

As far as you updated your question and now you need not Array offset, but index offset so @sawa solution will works fine for you

Answer (score 1):

Ariel is right. This is the best way to handle this, and it's not that bad

```
ary.each_with_index do |a, i|
  puts i + 1
  #other code
end
```

That is perfectly acceptable, and better than most of the solutions I've seen for this. I always thought this was what #inject was for...oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `map`

```
some_array = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
some_array_plus_offset_index = some_array.each_with_index.map {|item, i| [item, i + 1]}
some_array_plus_offset_index.each{|item, offset_index| some_func(item, offset_index) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in every ruby version:

```
%W(one two three).zip(1..3).each do |value, index|
  puts value, index
end
```

And for a generic array:

```
a.zip(1..a.length.each do |value, index|
  puts value, index
end
```

Comment: missing a bracket in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

```
offset = 2
some_array[offset..-1].each_with_index{|item, index| some_func(item, index+offset) }
```