# Counting in View Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, count, each

I've got a list of items I'm looping in an each in my show view. This is all perfectly fine. However, I would like to get a number infront of each item which increments with every loop ( i = 0, i++ you know the drill ).

Now, how can i do this in Rails? This is what I get by now:

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% @trip.triplocations.each do |tl| %>
  <article id="<%= dom_id(tl)  %>">
    <strong> <%= tl.title %> </strong>
      <p>
        <%= tl.description %>
      </p>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [**#each_with_index**](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) instead of instantiating a variable in view!

```
<% @trip.triplocations.each_with_index do |tl, i| %>
  <article id="<%= dom_id(tl) %>">
    <strong> <%= i %>. <%= tl.title %> </strong>
      <p>
        <%= tl.description %>
      </p>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That certainly worked! However; is it possible to start the i at 1? Since i want to use it as a visual numbering.

Comment: You can increase by 1 like this `<%= i+1 %>`. This should work but for more information take a look at [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646390/ruby-each-with-index-offset).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want this sort of code.

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% @trip.triplocations.each do |tl| %>
    <article id="<%= dom_id(tl)  %>">
        <strong> <%= tl.title %> </strong>
        <p>
            <%= i %>
            <%= tl.description %>

        </p>
    </article>
    <% i = i + 1 %> 
<% end %>
```

Note:

You can place the  code

```
<%= i %>
```

anywhere you want inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `++` operator in Ruby. Instead you use `+= 1`:

```
array = 'a'..'d'

i = 0
array.each do |element|
  puts "#{i} #{element}"
  i += 1
end
```

Prints

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

However, you should not do that because there is already a convenient method for that:

```
array = 'a'..'d'

array.each_with_index do |element, i|
  puts "#{i} #{element}"
end
```

There is another way of doing that specific to Rails. If you render collection using a partial you will have object_counter variable available where "object" is your model name. For example:

```
<%= render @trip.triplocations %>

<% # in views/triplocations/_triplocation.html.erb %>
<%= triplocation_counter %>
<%= triplocation.title %>
```